# Restriction Morphism of a Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have folowing question about a restriction morphism at a ringed space:

We have a Ring $R = k[T_1, T_2]$ that induces in canonial way the affine scheme $ (X, \mathcal{O}_X) := (\operatorname{Spec} R, \tilde{R})$. Let $U := D(T_1) \cup D(T_2)$ with $\Gamma(D(T_1),\mathcal{O}_X) = R_{T_1} = k[T_1^{\pm}, T_2] $ and $\Gamma(D(T_2),\mathcal{O}_X) = R_{T_2} = k[T_1, T_2^{\pm}] $. Using sheaf axiom / exactness of sequence $ 0 \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) \xrightarrow{d_0} \prod_{i=1,2}\Gamma(D(T_i),\mathcal{O}_X) \xrightarrow{d_1} \Gamma(D(T_1) \cap D(T_2),\mathcal{O}_X)\times \Gamma(D(T_2) \cap D(T_1),\mathcal{O}_X) $ defined by $d_0: s \to (s | _{D(T_i)})$ and $d_1: (s_i)_i \to (s_i |_{D(T_i) \cap D(T_j)}  - (s_j |_{D(T_i) \cap D(T_j)})_{i,j}$ it's easy to see that using this conditition we get $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) = R$. Futhermore we have $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = R$ as global intersection of an affine scheme.

My question is how I can deduce from this that the restriction morphism $d_2: R =\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) = R,  s \to s |_U$ must be an isomorphism?

Comment: I think if you prove $0 \to \Gamma(X, \mathscr{O}_X) \to \prod_{i=1,2} \cdots \to \mathrm{im}(d_1) \to 0$ is also exact when you compose with the restriction morphism, then the snake lemma should give the desired result.

Comment: Let $d_{3} : \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to \prod_{i=1,2} \Gamma(D(T_{i}),\mathcal{O}_{X})$ be the map whose components are the two restriction maps. Then $d_{0} \circ d_{2} = d_{3}$ and you can check that $d_{0}$ and $d_{3}$ have the same image.

Comment: Ok, but if the images of $d_0$ and $d_3$ are same I don´t see why we get the comclusion that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \cong \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$. We know that because of $U=D(T_1) \cup D(T_2)$ according to the sheaf axiom we can identity $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ with it's image under $d_0$, but how we can see that $ Im(d_3) \cong \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$?

Comment: @KarlPeter One can check that $d_{3}$ is injective; thus $d_{2}$ is injective. Moreover $d_{0}$ is injective by the sheaf axiom. Thus if $d_{0}$ and $d_{3}$ have the same image then $d_{2}$ is an isomorphism.