# Restriction of Global Section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $X = Spec(R)$ the induced affine scheme. I want at first prove that then for every open $U \subset X$ the restriction morphism $R =\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is injective.

The background of this question is my older thread [Restriction Morphism of a Scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349739/restriction-morphism-of-a-scheme) and the argument of @Minseon Shin:

Is it enough to look what happen in the image of the restriction map?
My idea: Maybe we can for some $x_p \in U$ compose the restriction morphism with canonical map to the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_p}$. Because $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_p} = R_{x_p}$ and $R$ integral domain the resulting map $R \to R_{x_p}$ should be injective, right?

In addition, does the injectivity $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ hold for more general conditions?
Maybe if $X$ is not affine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\eta$ be the generic point, then $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_{\eta}$ is injective, since it is just the map $R\to\text{Frac}(R)$, and the map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_{\eta}$ factors as
$$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_{\eta}$$

Then it follows that the map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is injective by elementary set theory.

Moreover, if $X$ is an integral scheme, by writing $X$ as a union of $Spec$ of integral domains, then we can show that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is injective by the above and the sheaf axioms.